# How to make a system with USB 3.0 slave that provides data to an FPGA?

Tags: usb, fpga

I consider making a system with USB 3.0 slave interface that provides data to an FPGA, where the connection should allow full utilization of the available USB 3.0 speed.

What external components are typically required, e.g. IC, and what functionality is typically placed in the FPGAs?

Comment: Please add a comment when down voting, otherwise I can never learn.

Comment: I'll comment on behalf of the downvoter. This question is both - unclear, too broad and asking for product recommendation, which is off-topic. There is no single "USB interface" specification. There are hundreds of thousands different USB interface ICs. There are hundreds or thousands of different FPGAs around.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I think that mentioning some example of interconnect IC when connecting USB 3.0 to an FPGA will be a great help in understanding the general requirements.  Otherwise just labeling the IC as an "USB PHY" may also suffice.

Comment: You might want to ask about methods of interfacing and you requirements instead. A simplest solution would be to have some kind of USB-serial converter connected to a UART implemented in your FPGA. But it has limitations. And again, this is not what you have asked.

Comment: It is amazing how this forum can be dysfunctional sometimes.  The question was asked based on an actual need, and after I have tried to find the answer myself on both Intel/Altera, Xilinx and related board providers homepages, even though I am generally very experience in the field.  Also interesting how there is more effort in putting this question on hold, than providing an actual answer, or a reference to a duplicate answer.  Please reflect over whether the damage made by putting a question on hold is larger than the damage made by having skilled engineers ask actual questions.

Comment: The question was terminated because you exhibited no effort to access the problem complexity. You want to access **slave** USB3 device from FPGA. This means that you must implement USB3 HOST function. USB host is a tremendously complex logic design on the top of rare and expensive PHY, which would require either a 10-men-years effort to develop, or buy an expensive (>$100K) RTL DesignWare IP from places like Synopsys, plus still a year of wrap-compile-fit-debug effort. Your question is nearly as "how do I go making a SuperComputer in my garage"?

Comment: @Ale..chenski: Thanks for the comment.  I can see that the question is unclear, since what I want is to make a system with USB slave interface that provides data to an FPGA.  None of the comments prior to putting the question on hold mentioned any such problem with the question, so it is not clear that it was the reason for putting the question on hold.  Even though the question was unclear, one helpful answers was received, so the question was not that bad anyway ;-)

Comment: So, you are now reversing your question? Currently the question is even more obscure. Now it looks like you want to make a USB3 peripheral (USB device) and interface it to FPGA (USB host).

Comment: For this question, there is likely no update that will ever satisfy the critics, now that the decision has been made to downvote and hold this question. 
 But none can dispute that the question gave a valuable answer, which is what this forum is about :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently completed a project where we used the [FTDI FT600Q](https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT600.html) to pass data from an ADC, through an FPGA, and out to a laptop over USB 3.0. This chip has a parallel interface to connect to an FPGA. It should be able to interface with basically any FPGA.

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful information.  What FPGA did you use?  Did you need additional USB 3.0 core in the FPGA?  Do you know of any mainstream FPGA with build in USB 3.0 PHY, so the FTDI FT600/1 can be skipped?

Comment: No, this chip allowed us to avoid any USB 3.0 cores within the FPGA itself. We used the Mojo v3 FPGA Development Board (Sparkfun DEV-11953) which is based on a Spartan-6. I'm not personally aware of any FPGAs with a built-in USB PHY, but that doesn't mean they aren't out there somewhere

Comment: Thanks again, that is great information, and helps me a lot.

Comment: This answer refers to making a USB3 **device**, while the OP wants to implement **USB3 host" within FPGA to interface with "full USB3 capability" of a device. Wrong answer.

Comment: You are correct, the chip I listed implements USB device functionality. If OP wants host capability, they will need to look elsewhere. I missed that in my initial reading of the question.